# Getting Thunderbird External Editor working with Emacs

Tags: emacs, thunderbird

I am trying to get the External Editor extension for thunderbird to work, so that I can use Emacs to compose emails. I haven't had much luck in getting this to work. Can anyone describe the steps they used to make this work. I think that my first problem is that the external editor plugin itself is not working, as I cannot even get it to work with gedit.

http://globs.org/download.php

Running:

- Ubuntu 11.10
- Emacs 23
- Not sure which version of External Editor to use
- The latest Thunderbird from the main repositories

Comment: you should supply some more information (operating system, thunderbird version, etc.). External Editor 1.0.0 is working fine for me with thunderbird 8 and emacs 23.

Comment: @mitch_feaster I just added that information. Thanks

Comment: did you actually install External Editor? If so, did you set up your external editor in the add-on preferences? If you want help you need to tell us exactly what you've already done and exactly what's not working (error messages, etc).

Comment: I'm on icedove (aka thunderbird) 10.0.4, Debian testing, and could not get it to work. I tried Emacs23 (both /usr/bin/emacs and /usr/bin/emacsclient) as well as Emacs24 (/usr/bin/emacs-snapshot), but trying to open the external editor via the Tools menu is always a no-op. No error message, just nothing.

Answer (score 1):

In the external editor settings (Tools, Add-ons, Extensions, External Editor Preferences), make sure to put in the path to emacs where it says "Text Editor". I'm doing this on OS X, so here's what it says for me:

```
/Applications/Emacs.app/Contents/MacOS/Emacs
```

You would want to put in the location of your emacs executable: likely something like:

```
/usr/bin/emacs.
```